# Why Secure Local Storage returns null sometimes?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

Hi i am using firebase google auth and i am storing data in secure local storage.
i am checking the user if the user is exist on every route by getting the user from the local stroage  the application is working fine but sometimes my secure local storage
userData object return null. But in the application tab the local storage userData object is present there.

```
import secureLocalStorage from 'react-secure-storage'

const PrivateRoute = ({ children, route }) => {
  
  const ability = useContext(AbilityContext)
  const user = JSON.parse(secureLocalStorage.getItem('userData'))

 if (!user) {
      console.log("In navigate to login")
      console.log(JSON.parse(secureLocalStorage.getItem('userData')))
      console.log(user)
      return <Navigate to='/login' />
    }
  

}
```

If the user is not exist the application is navigated to the Login page. It sometimes occurs when i refresh the page.

[image]

I have also attached the screenshot of the console tab when the local stroage is null.

[image]

And a Screen shot of the application tab where the secure local storage userData object is actually present there. But returns Null.

Answer (score 0):

The library is designed in a way that, First it create a fingerprint for the browser, This is by checking a lots of parameters including browser width user agent and etc, Then by using this key, The library will try to decrypt all the data which is stored in the localStorage, If its unable to decrypt any data, it will simply skip the data, by default it wont remove from the local storage

So when we change the browser to mobile view through inspect / tool, Then the browser properties will get changed, especially maximum width and user agent, So when we refresh the website, library will create a secure key, But this time it will be different from the last, So it wont decrypt the data.

So when we save the most sensitive data on the secure local storage, When the data is not present, we need to assume that the browser has been compromised and this should be the expected behavior. This should reflect in the way we handle the data too.

For example: If we are saving auth token and other user parameter which is used authenticate the user to the platform. If the data is not present we should logout the user

### Edit

This issue has been fixed in the latest version of `react-secure-storage@1.1.0`